# How do I see which files I have open in command-T

Tags: vim, plugins

I'm using the vim plugin Command-T. How do I see which files I have open in command-T?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:ls
```

or

```
:buffers
```

gives you a list of currently opened buffers.

Comment: Thanks. From the ls command how do I select the buffer I'd like to go to?

Comment: Try this plugin-free mapping for super quick buffer navigation: `nnoremap gb :buffers<CR>:b<Space>`. Or simply use Command-T's own `:CommandTBuffer` command.